# Posting data to Codeigniter From AFNetworking

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode, codeigniter, afnetworking

I have a website built on codeigniter that works fine. I'm currently building an iPhone app for said site. It uses AFNetworking to communicate with the codeigniter controllers. I have used AFNetworking with iPhone development before and never had a problem.

Here I am not receiving any post data to the codeigniter controller. But I know it's making a connection from the app because if I just echo a string I get a response in the console.

Alternatively, I made a test php script on a different server and just echo'd the $_POST[] vars, and it worked, however I can not get them to POST with codeigniter.

Is there a setting somewhere in codeigniter that disallows posting from external sources? Or is there something i'm missing.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check to see if you have CRSF enabled. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/security.html

Comment: Ah nope :( it's disabled. Got excited for a minute. But thanks for the try.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two ways to access post variables using codeigniter.

I am using AFNetworking in my iOS project and I can access the post variables via

```
$post = $this->input->post();
```

There's also this method for JSON post

```
$post = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
```